# Bluetooth Audio Chip SOC from Microchip?

Tags: audio, identification, bluetooth

I recently purchased  a ShinePine Bluetooth Karaoke microphone from Amazon UK.  It provides Bluetooth, echo, pitch changer, mic input,  LEDS, Card Reader,  control switches as possibly in the same chip. Made in China. I am trying to identify the chip. The 24MHz crystal on on the left side of the image, the Bluetooth PCB antenna above the IC.

[image: Bluetooth chip]

The part number search of AC208P in Google brought up the very similar but not identical  Microchip  IS2083 Bluetooth  Stereo Audio SoC https://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/IS2083, but in a different package.   Is the chip in my image a clone of the Microchip version please?

Comment: Trace the circuit. Do the pin functions match?

Answer (score 3):

It has nothing to do with Microchip... the part you link is apparently only available as BGA.

The part is from a manufacturer called Zuhai Jie Li. See this: [Indentifying a JL chip in a Bluetooth](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/491233/indentifying-a-jl-chip-in-a-bluetooth). It might be a proprietary part.