# Identify a chip

Tags: identification, obd

[image: obd PCB board]

So I cannot identify this chip by name I am not an electrical engineer I come from IT programming background but I am interested in a wide array of things, so I thought that I might ask you guys since this is your field of expertise :)
The chip I am talking about is AB21BP0H711-29C4. I just want to find some documentation about this chip and understand how they scam people. Btw this is a boar of elm that won't connect to ECU and won't respond to basic elm command even the version it only returns the voltage that's it. I suspect this to be a Bluetooth chip by the antenna connection and the fact that there is nothing aside from traces on the other side of the board hence one picture.
For anyone wondering I got my money back and the product was placed high with 180 bought and 4.7 star rating also from legit seller not a "scam_account123" and no it wasn't on AliExpress :) anyway at some point iam sure it was from ali.

Comment: Probably some proprietary IC. I recognize a very similar question asked before: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/491233/indentifying-a-jl-chip-in-a-bluetooth. So at least that gets you as far as identifying the quite obscure silicon vendor.

Comment: What makes you think that there's any scam going on?

Comment: Just because a board doesn't work doesn't mean it is a scam. It could be: (a) legitimate board that happens to be broken in some way; (b) legitimate board with substandard (possibly counterfeit, with or without the knowledge of the board manufacturer) components that fail relatively frequently; (c) "scam" board made with junk parts that would never work properly.

Comment: If it was a scam they wouldn't make an actual circuit board with antennas and stuff. They'd put a blinking LED in a box.

Comment: Older OBDII dongles had a separate MCU, but the folks at ZJL 珠海杰理 appear quite capable of combining the MCU with BT. Their stated main business interest is SOCs for IOT and such like. I don't think it's a scam at all, despite your inability to get this particular item to work. Once they sell the silicon there are many ways for it to not work (bad assembly, bad external components, bad software etc.)

Comment: Based on the folded trace antenna, it's almost certainly a radio of some sort (possibly BT, sure)... from the logo it's likely a [ZhuHai JieLi](https://www.zh-jieli.com/) part...

Answer (score 1):

For information, I have just encountered this same microcontroller (AB21BP0H711-29C4) In a brand product "SoundLogic" , Simple a 2 meters strip of 60 RGB leds.
Here is the only information I have, if it can helps someone.
I will come back if I found more about it.

[image: article désignation]
[image: carte interne]

Comment: So this confirms Spehro Pefhany's assumption that the *AB21BP0H711-29C4* IC is likely an MCU with an integrated radio module.