Identify IC marked AC1819E8L6259A0 or the purpose of the whole board
What is this part used for? How do I identify it? The marking text reads "AC1819E8L6259A0."
I would like to figure out this tiny board's purpose. I found it blinking in my car outside of its casing, nothing but this motherboard and small battery.



It wouldn't let me add pic I can send it to you email or text even oh wait here's a link to view them @jsotla

what message do you get when you try to attach a picture?

When I made post it said pic too big now I don't know how to add pic after the fact but it let me make a link Join this shared album (Electronic).
https://groupshare.samsungcloud.com/invitation/gallery/FxqHrnMfOt

Oh okay I've done that now thank you.

Cropping images or saving them in a less expensive format isn't hard... and there is no picture appearing in the link provided.

Weird when I click it it takes me to the pics I'll try cropping not sure how to save in different format on my cell one sec

In particular, we really need know which IC package that is used . "IC" could be anything between SOT23 to QFP144 to DIP28.

Ok so this manufacturer pops up here from time to time. It's an obscure Chinese one which does not always offer datasheets - I can't tell if it's because the parts are proprietary or just because it's a crappy vendor. See https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/491233/indentifying-a-jl-chip-in-a-bluetooth. Very likely the IC is some manner of Bluetooth or similar wireless controller.

I manged to get second Pic of whole board  but thank you it took me long time to fig out what to call the thing before asking my question your help is appreciated

Any more context? It could be part of the car's bluetooth functionality, wireless speakers, multimedia equipment etc. Clearly some low price PCBA. Quite unlikely to be related with the main purpose of the car - driving.

I assumed as much truthfully I thought maybe my bf found some Chinese temu tracker thing and put it in my trunk cause it's not mine when I take things apart it's cause they are broke and I won't to learn about them thus thing is still powered and blinking under my spare tire

@lundin was that the context you were looking for I reliaze I'm not a electrical whiz but I am a great a qwick leaner and surly appreciate your time in having answered my question thank you

So maybe it doesn't belong to the car at all? It's a RF chip but short distance 2.4GHz stuff, likely commercial class bluetooth/BLE which means the range is <100m, particularly with the crappy PCB antenna. Maybe it belongs to a garage port remote control or such? The hole in the middle of the PCB is curious though, are there components on both sides?

No on otherside  is a peel and stick type foam circle holding the red and blck wire to battery to board and just gold inlaid type lines sorry I know that's no technical term but I assume they lay behind what might be called silkscreen or something there are three layers to a board correct. Sorry I'm trying to learn some basics quickly to keep up with any responses

It looks like it has a 2.4GHz antenna on it, so it's likely BLE or Wifi to usb. There is no battery on it on the top of the unit.

As nanash1 mentioned, the IC is a Bluetooth controller of some sort.
The squiggly line (circled in red) is an antenna.

The thing circled in blue is a switch to turn the device on and off.  A garage door remote control wouldn't usually have a power switch.  They usually just have a pushbutton (or two.)
Circled in black are the solder pads and mounting points for a couple of earphone jacks.  One is probably to connect to a speaker (or to the car radio) while the other would be for a microphone.
My best guess is that the circuit board was designed as a Bluetooth handsfree device to speak on a phone while driving.
The jacks for connecting a microphone and connecting to a speaker are missing.  The lower jack was installed, but appears to have been removed forcibly.
Either you've found a broken handsfree telephone adapter or you've found a handsfree telephone adapter that is being misused as a Bluetooth beacon.
Use your phone to scan for Bluetooth devices and see if you can find one that identifies as an audio or handsfree device.

Wow thank you. I'll try scanning now just out of curiosity would you be able to track this item like like one of them air tags or something cuz I know Skullcandy headphones can be tracked if they're lost just curious

Okay so oddly enough I scanned for devices after flipping it's switch the light cane on and only avaiable device was titled "cooler bag" I turn it off and it shows for available devices" Vertuo_dv6_70b8f64c4782 when I tried to pair to this it said an app must be installed when I attempted to pair to collier bag it said would you like to pair so I assumed it was the gadget and shut it off but that's weird why didn't the. Vert thing show when  the gadget is on but only when off

It's a  a Jieli (杰理芯片) Bluetooth MCU, possibly a AC6969A.
I think it's a AC6969A, because the marking characters after the dash seem to match with the last characters of the product number on Jieli ICs (see this question for an example). The AC6969A is the only one I could find with 9A at the end and a SOP16 package.
